# Why does an enum.ToString box/callvirt, instead of pushing address and call? Are there any other special cases?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

I have this framework I wrote a couple months ago that generates a class for calling this performance service. Consumers of the framework create an interface with methods, annotate with attributes, and call a factory method that creates the implementation of the interface they can use to call this performance service. The service only supports two data string and long. I use reflection emit with collectable assemblies to generate the class that implements the interface.

Everything has been working good, but today someone told me they were getting an AV when they tried to pass in a enum that would be converted to a string. In the code there is a check to see if the type is a value type and if so push the address (ldarga or ldflda depending on the interface the consumer created) and then call ToString. So I created a little debug app, and I saw the C# compiler will box an enum and then call ToString on the boxed enum.

So like I am kinda confused. Is the way I am handling value types incorrect? Is the IL the C# compiler generates for toString on enum the correct way to do? Are there any other special cases like this

Update with answer:
so it looks like i need to see if the value type implements tostring and if it doesnt box. For value types i guess this applies to the object methods, tostring, gethashcode, equals.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    public struct H
    {
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Test<AttributeTargets>(AttributeTargets.ReturnValue); //-- fails
            //Test<int>(10); //-- works
           // TestBox<AttributeTargets>(AttributeTargets.ReturnValue); //-- works
            //Test<H>(new H()); // fails
            TestCorrect<H>(new H()); // works 
            TestCorrect<int>(10); // works 

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TestCorrect<T>(T t)
    where T : struct
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod(
                "ToString",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null,
                Type.EmptyTypes,
                null);

            var m = new DynamicMethod("x", typeof(string), new[] { typeof(T) });
            var i = m.GetILGenerator();
            if (method.DeclaringType == typeof(T))
            {
                i.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga, 0);
                i.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
            }
            else
            {
                i.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                i.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(T));
                i.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, method);
            }

            i.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            string result = (m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, string>)) as Func<T, string>)(t);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static void Test<T>(T t)
            where T : struct
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod(
                "ToString",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null,
                Type.EmptyTypes,
                null);

            var m = new DynamicMethod("x", typeof(string), new[] { typeof(T) });
            var i = m.GetILGenerator();
            i.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga, 0);
            i.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
            i.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            string result = (m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, string>)) as Func<T, string>)(t);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static void TestBox<T>(T t)
            where T : struct
        {
            // this is how the C# compiler call to string on enum.
            MethodInfo method = typeof(T).GetMethod(
                "ToString",
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null,
                Type.EmptyTypes,
                null);

            var m = new DynamicMethod("x", typeof(string), new[] { typeof(T) });
            var i = m.GetILGenerator();
            i.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            i.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(T));
            i.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, method);
            i.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
            string result = (m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, string>)) as Func<T, string>)(t);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to post some code or no one can help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting an AV"?

Comment: Code is not needed heee, IMHO. It is understandable what the OP tries to do.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Yes, but if you then call the underlying type's `ToString` method, you don't get the enumeration name, you get its underlying value.

Comment: @hvd good point, absolutely right.

Comment: Jon Skeet: I tried just now and get an "Operation Could destablize runtime error", my coworker though was getting a C0000005 when use this framework in a service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An enumeration type doesn't override its `ToString()` method, so for any enumeration type `e`, `e.ToString()` resolves to `Enum.ToString`. This method is defined on a reference type (`Enum` is a reference type), so to call this method, the implicit `this` argument needs to be a boxed value.

Most other value types, such as `int`, do provide an overridden `ToString` method directly on the value type itself.

From the specification:

> **I.12.1.6.2.4 Calling methods**
>
> Static methods on value types are handled no differently from static methods on an ordinary class: use a `call` instruction with a metadata token specifying the value type as the class of the method. Non-static methods (i.e., instance and virtual methods) are supported on value types, but they are given special treatment. A non-static method on a reference type (rather than a value type) expects a **this** pointer that is an instance of that class. This makes sense for reference types, since they have identity and the **this** pointer represents that identity. Value types, however, have identity only when boxed. To address this issue, the **this** pointer on a non-static method of a value type is a byref parameter of the value type rather than an ordinary by-value parameter.
>
> A non-static method on a value type can be called in the following ways:
>
> - For unboxed instances of a value type, the exact type is known statically. The `call` 
>     instruction can be used to invoke the function, passing as the first parameter (the this 
>     pointer) the address of the instance. The metadata token used with the `call` instruction 
>     shall specify the value type itself as the class of the method.
> - Given a boxed instance of a value type, there are three cases to consider:
>
>   - Instance or virtual methods introduced on the value type itself: unbox the 
>       instance and call the method directly using the value type as the class of the 
>       method.
>   - Virtual methods inherited from a base class: use the `callvirt` instruction and 
>       specify the method on the `System.Object`, `System.ValueType` or `System.Enum` class as appropriate.
>   - Virtual methods on interfaces implemented by the value type: use the `callvirt` 
>       instruction and specify the method on the interface type.

Answer (score 5):

Consider:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestFoo(Foo.A);
        TestEnum(Foo.B);
        TestGenerics(Foo.C);
    }
    static string TestFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo.ToString();
    }
    static string TestEnum(Enum foo)
    {
        return foo.ToString();
    }
    static string TestGenerics<T>(T foo)
    {
        return foo.ToString();
    }
}

enum Foo
{
    A, B, C
}
```

This generates the IL:

```
.class private auto ansi sealed Foo
    extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
    .field public static literal valuetype Foo A = int32(0)

    .field public static literal valuetype Foo B = int32(1)

    .field public static literal valuetype Foo C = int32(2)

    .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__

}
```

Note that `Foo` does not override `ToString()`. The compiler potentially *could*, but: it doesn't. This is the single main reason for seeing a box - if a `struct` doesn't `override` an `object.` method, you can't call that method without boxing it. Simple as. Well, not *quite* that simple - the compiler can also use *constrained call*, which defers that final decision to the JIT: if the type overrides the method, it will call it direct - otherwise it will box. This is exactly what the compiler *does* emit in the two cases where it isn't already a reference-type (note: anything passed as `Enum` is already boxed; `Enum` is a reference-type):

```
.method private hidebysig static string TestFoo(valuetype Foo foo) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarga.s foo
    L_0002: constrained. Foo
    L_0008: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    L_000d: ret 
}

# NOTE: in this example, foo is **already** boxed before it comes in, hence
# no attempt at constrained-call
.method private hidebysig static string TestEnum(class [mscorlib]System.Enum foo) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    L_0006: ret 
}
.method private hidebysig static string TestGenerics<T>(!!T foo) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarga.s foo
    L_0002: constrained. !!T
    L_0008: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    L_000d: ret 
}
```

Now, it *could* be that the JIT and CLI work some voodoo there that makes the constrained call work despite the presence of an overload, but: if it doesn't, at least this explains (hopefully) *why* it is boxing, and demonstrates that the compiler tried really quite hard to get it to not box (via the *constrained* call).

Comment: This might be a stupid question - but `System.Enum` overrides `ToString`. So couldn't the compiler emit a virtual call, without the boxing?

Comment: @dcastro that just moves the problem: the compiler can't call `base.ToString()` without boxing itself. It would need to move a non-trivial amount of code into the enum type itself to do it without boxing, I suspect. But: I agree it could probably do *more than it does*.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize `System.Enum` is a reference type, which explains why it would still have to be boxed.